# Connect PC with 4K TV

Tags: hdmi, nvidia-geforce, 4k-resolution

First I hope I've chosen the right site since I just signed up.

So I wanted to ask what do I have to do to connect my PC with the GTX 680 inside to my Samsung UHD HU6950 TV.

I heard that HDMI 1.4 does support 4K at 24 Hz. Is that true? 
So I would need a HDMI 2.0 cable to run at 60 Hz but does my GFX card support that? I can't find the info on the Nvidia site of my GFX card.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: The HDMI 1.4 specification is published.  You can verify if HDMI 1.4 supports 4K content easily enough.  What graphic card do you have exactly?  GTX 680 isn't enough to go on there are about 20 different versions of the GTX 680.

Comment: @Ramhound I have the EVGA GTX 680 SC Signature 2GB GDDR 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA provides a very good overview over their GPUs' specifications. [Here are the specs for the GTX 680 GPU](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-680/specifications):

> Maximum Digital Resolution<sup>4</sup>: 4096x2160
>
> [...]
>
> 4 - **3840x2160 at 30Hz or 4096x2160 at 24Hz supported over HDMI.** 4096x2160 (including 3840x2160) at 60Hz supported over Displayport. Support for 4k tiled MST displays requires 326.19 driver or later.

(Emphasis mine.)

These specifications are valid for all GTX 680 cards available. You cannot upgrade to HDMI 2.0 without buying a new graphics card.

Comment: Thank you. I connected the PC and TV but I does display the desktop for a very short time then it turns black and after a few seconds it displays it again and so on. What might be the cause of this?

Comment: It could be your cable not being good enough. How long is it? If you still have the packaging, what type is it? A “High Speed HDMI Cable”?

Comment: I don't know exactly how long it is but it must be somewhere between 2 and 3 meters. It should be a high speed HDMI cable yes, its written on it.

Comment: I see. That shouldn’t pose a problem. Maybe to cable is otherwise broken and/or low-quality. Try another one to be sure.

Comment: well I guess I have to buy a new one then... Wouls it also work with a DP to HDMI cable? Because my gfx card has no second HDMI port but a DP.

Comment: That’s a definite “maybe”. ;) The odds are better with “pure” HDMI.